# cv2.aruco does not be shown in pylance popup window(Visual Studio Code)

Tags: python, opencv

[cv2.aruco do not show in pylance popup window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOQfF.png)

When I used OpenCV with python in Visual Studio Code, I can't find "aruco" after I wrote "cv2.".
Why?

I could run this code.
It seems I installed OpenCV correctly.

```
import cv2
aruco_dictionary = cv2.aruco.Dictionary_get(cv2.aruco.DICT_7X7_250)
```

[pip list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMelR.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install **exactly one** of the available packages.

For `aruco`, you need the package with **contrib** modules.

First remove all packages, then install just one.